# SqlException: Invalid column name - Column doesnt exist

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I am in the process of moving a database from one server to another. But now I am getting the error 'Invalid column name msrepl_tran_version'. This is a column which I deleted off the new database as it was related to replication which I no longer need.

I have recreated the Datasets, done a search for anything with msrepl_tran_version in the entire solution and nothing. I can't see where it is referencing this column from, it doesn't exist!

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please specify where and when you get that error. It seems that you are working in a Visual Studio development environment because you mention a dataset but it is not clear.

Comment: Yes, I am working in Visual Studio 2010. The error occurs on calling the .Update command of a table adapter.

Comment: @baked - I presume there is a trigger on the table that still references that column then. Instead of trying to remove it manually [use the specified methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms147833(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: @MartinSmith There doesn't appear to be any triggers, although I have never worked with triggers before so I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It is a transactional replication column and not straight forward to remove, it seems you haven't totally removed it...

[how to remove msrepltranversion column](http://kevine323.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/how-to-remove-msrepltranversion-column.html)

Comment: That article is about things that would prevent the column removal. Looks like they have actually succeeded in removing the column (deleting it in the SSMS designer would drop the associated constraints) but not everything that references it.

Comment: I have already removed all the constraints that are associated with replication. Thanks though, wish I had that script before I started :)